# Error while Connecting to a mongo server from a spring boot application when running in a docker locally

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-container, docker-network

I built a REST API using spring boot frame work. In the application I am trying to connect to mongo servers which I am successfully connected to while running in an IDE.

But when I try to run it in a docker I am facing the below issue.

Please help me solve it.

com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: qa-***mongo02.aws.*****.local: Name or service not known

Comment: Check this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55202585/cannot-connect-to-mongodb-container-host).

Comment: @hamadaj i am new to docker and mongodb. please tell me do we need another mongo container to connect to a production server ?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my docker-compose.yml
Hope this helps.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    playground_spring_test1_java:
        container_name: playground_spring_test1_java
        build:
            context: ./demo
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        stdin_open: true
        # env_file:
        #     - ./dev.env
        tty: true

        volumes:
            - "./demo:/app"
        ports:
            - 80:8080


    playground_spring_test1_mongo:
        container_name: playground_spring_test1_mongo
        image: mongo
        volumes:
            - playground_spring_test1_mongo_data:/data/db
        ports:
            - 27017:27017

volumes:
  playground_spring_test1_mongo_data:
```

Im using MongoTemplate and my `application.properties` is-

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://playground_spring_test1_mongo:27017/?authSource=admin
```

Comment: thanks for replying, are you using a local server connection ?

Comment: yes, you can use container name as hostname for local server connection....

Comment: yeah. i tried and it helped to. but my question is different. i am trying to connect to a private server which i have access to. i can connect to that server in IDE but i am unable to connect through docker. and that connection requires a openvpn connection which i do have. why am i unable to access to that server. can you please tell me. where am i doing wrong.